# Programmatically set Keyboard.Key icon

Tags: java, android, keyboard, icons

I'm using Android's `Keyboard` and `KeyboardView` classes to make a custom keyboard for an `EditText` (using this [tutorial](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm)).

In my keyboard.xml file, I've set an icon for my shift key. However, I have another icon to display when shift is activated. However, I [can't find](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android%3akeyIcon) a method that allows me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a setter method, there is a [public icon field](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#icon) in the Keyboard.Key class. Simply reassign the value of this field to change a key's icon.

```
Keyboard.Key key = findKey(myKeyboard, keyCode);
key.icon = myDrawable;

private Keyboard.Key findKey(Keyboard keyboard, int primaryCode) {
  for (Keyboard.Key key : keyboard.getKeys()) {
    if (key.codes[0] == primaryCode) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Use Keyboard.Key.icon = yourDrawable;

Answer (score 0):

For finding shift key in your keyboard, just use

```
Keyboard.Key shiftedKey = keyboard.getKeys().get(keyboard.getShiftKeyIndex())
```